# White Blank screen and issue to get thumbnail in

Tags: post-thumbnails

```
    <section id="container" class="one-column">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <div class="gridBox">
            <div class="boxes-container">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'         => 'post', 
                        'category_name'     => 'portfolio',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1
                    );

                    // The Query
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    // The Loop
                    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                        $c = 1;     // counter
                        $bpr = 4;   // number of column in each row

                        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                            ?>
                                <div class="grid-boxes <?php echo (($c != $bpr) ? 'margin_right' : ''); ?>">
                                    <div class="grid-thumbnail">
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>


                                          <div class="blog-image" style="background: url('<?php
                                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {$large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
                                                echo '$large_image_url[0]';
                                                ?>') no-repeat;">
                                          </div>


                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/no-thumbnail.jpg" alt="No Thumbnail" />
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php

                            // we add a condition here to see if counter is equal to the number of column.
                            if( $c == $bpr ) {
                                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                                $c = 0;     // back the counter to 0 if the condition above is true.
                            }
                            $c++;           // increment counter of 1 until it hits the limit of column of every row.

                        endwhile;

                    /* Restore original Post Data */
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div><!-- #content -->

    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The original `category.php` worked but when I edited with `blog-image` class to show background image in grid box, it gave me error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE.

I tried to work around that `blog-image`.

Only when reverted back to just one line: `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` it worked.

Puzzled because `while` or `endwhile` is there.

Comment: `if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {` is missing the closing `}`

Comment: Glad you got the problem fixed.  Please consider writing an answer and accepting it so that the question shows as resolved.